# why strcpy return char * and not char

Tags: c

A lot of string functions return a pointer but What are the Advantages of return a pointer to destination and return destination?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *sstrcpy ( char *destination, const char *source ){ //return a pointer to destination

    while ((*destination++ = *source++));
    *destination='\0';

return destination;
}

char sstrcpy2 ( char *destination, const char *source ){ //return destination

    while ((*destination++ = *source++));
    *destination='\0';

    return *destination;
}

int main(void){
    char source[] = "Well done is better than well said";
    char destination[40];

    sstrcpy ( destination, source );
    printf ( "%s\n", destination);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` can only represent a single symbol

Comment: Regarding your sentence `return a pointer to destination and return destination`, returning a char doesn't return the entire string. It only returns a single character (effectively a number), which is an ASCII representation of that single character. If you don't return a pointer (or a char array), you won't have access to the remaining characters of that string.

Comment: @jweyrich so is char sstrcpy2 incorrect?

Comment: @jhonnna absolutely.

Comment: `sstrcpy2` is simply returning `'\0'`

Comment: @jweyrich so why it works?

Comment: @jhonnna because you're not using the return value of `sstrcpy2` for anything. The function copies correctly, but returns a value that has no real use. Try this: `char result = sstrcpy ( destination, source ); printf ( "%s\n", result);` -- first thing you'll notice is that you _cannot_ use `%s` to print a single char. And even if you could, it wouldn't contain your entire string.

Comment: It "works" in that the destination holds a copy of the source, but it does not "work" in returning a pointer to the destination.  Your example code does nothing with the return value, you won't see the effects.

Comment: also, `sstrcpy` seems like it's performing the function of `stpcpy` rather than `strcpy`, as it is returning a pointer to the end of the string rather than the beginning.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons okay, I understand now

Comment: The last line with explicit null termination shouldn't be needed when writing an obfuscated while loop. But since you wrote an unredable, obfuscated while loop, you can't even tell this yourself. This is the whole reason why code like `while (*destination++ = *source++);` shouldn't be used.

Comment: Not only does returning `char` not return the entire string, *C does not provide a mechanism* that could return the entire string directly, because strings are (content of) arrays, and arrays can neither be passed to nor returned from functions.  Instead, pointers to array contents are passed and / or returned, which is exactly what you see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to give the possibility to chain the functions. I.e. to pass one function result as a parameter to another one.

```
sstrcpy ( destination2, sstrcpy ( destination1, source ));
```

As for the proposed `sstrcpy2` - it will only return a single, the last character of the copied string, which is apparently `\0` in your implementation, which is rather useless in most cases.

**Update:**
  Note that the implementation `sstrcpy` is incorrect as is, it will return the value of `destination`, which was already moved to the end of the string, and not the pointer to the beginning of it. Alternatively I would suggest saving the original pointer and increment it's copy instead:

```
char *sstrcpy ( char *destination, const char *source ){ //return a pointer to destination

    char *dst = destination;
    while ((*dst++ = *source++));
    *dst='\0';

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Note that *neither* of OP's implementations are correct, and the first one, used in your example, would set `destination2` to an empty string, contrary to expectations.

Comment: @rici Why? The `destination` is incremented, but it is passed by value. The last character is set to `\0`, not the first one. Update: Oh, wait. I see

Comment: The issue is that the value returned is a pointer to the end of the string rather than the beginning, so the second `sstrcpy` will be copying beginning from `'\0'`.

Comment: I think the (ir)rationale is rather that you should be able to write crap like `str = strcpy(str, "hello");`, which is approximately just as stupid as chaining multiple strcpy calls in the same expression. Don't do either, please.

Comment: @Lundin Chaining multiple `strcpy` is *on par* with `a=b=c`. Even though the specific example was just to accommodate the OPs example. These do not have to be the same functions, but just  *some* string functions. Such as `strcat`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Until some nutjob starts writing code like `strcpy(&str[index()], strcpy(&str[index()], "hello"));` just because they can. And then we have unspecified order of evaluation, after which all manner of subtle bugs are unleashed.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that some practices are better than the others. Personally I avoid the forementioned `a=b=c` constructs.

Comment: I prefer `a[i++] = b[i++] = c[i++];` myself.

Answer (score 1):

Bug 1: you return the end of the string, not the beginning.
Bug 2: you add 2 null terminators at the end, instead of 1.

The correct implementation should be something along the lines of:

```
char* sstrcpy (char*restrict dst, const char*restrict src)
{
  char* original = dst;
  for(*dst = *src; *src != '\0'; dst++, src++)
  {
    *dst = *src;
  }
  return original;
}
```

where `restrict` is a contract with the caller that `dst` and `src` don't overlap. Please note that this might still be naive implementation - it is fine for small microcontrollers, but when it comes to library implementations of strcpy for 32 bit systems, they will work with aligned chunks of data.

---

> What are the Advantages of return a pointer to destination and return destination?

There are no advantages whatsoever; the standard library is filled with oddities. This allows two kinds of pointless obfuscation:

```
// Bad code, do not use!

/*1*/ str = strcpy(str, src); // pointless and potentially dangerous

/*2*/ strcpy(str2, strcpy(str1, src)); // pointless and potentially dangerous
```

This in turn allows side effects in parameter evaluation to cause bugs, so it is dangerous. Don't write crap like that. The correct versions are:

```
/*1*/ strcpy(str, src);

/*2*/ strcpy(str1, src);
      strcpy(str2, str1);
```

The latter versions are safer and easier to read. The resulting machine code will be identical.

Comment: I know you were just influenced by OP, but the arguments to `strcpy` are `strcpy(dst, src)`.

Comment: not so easy with the mobile interface, otherwise I would have.