# Functions been used as pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm doing an exercise for my college and I am somewhat lost on pointers.

The whole exercise is telling us to make a function `char *mystrcpy(char *dest, char *src)`. So what we need is to make an already included in <string.h> by ourselves.

It's not that hard as for the logical steps of the function, but i don't get why we need to use the function `char *mystrcpy()` as a pointer. Also how do we use functions as pointers and why?

Comment: Not clear what you mean "use a function as a pointer". The only thing such a signature means is that the function return type is a pointer. And this is a convention for the standard string functions to return pointers to a result. Why it is is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682897/why-strcpy-return-char-and-not-char/50682940#50682940

Comment: ah okay thanks a lot! Yeah I think that would do :D

Comment: Hint: the `mystrcpy` you're supposed to write is two lines long (excluding `{ }` and the `char *mystrcpy(char *dest, char *src)` itself). It should be the same as the standard `strcpy` function from `<string.h>`

Comment: Yeah, haven't seen yet the code of the original, wanted to try on my own first! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a pointer to function but a function that return a pointer.
like :

```
   char* strcpy(char* destination, const char* source);
```

that return a pointer to destination.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought, we were assigning the function strcpy() as a function. Okay, thanks a lot!